# ios develop detect cellphone turn off

Tags: ios

Is it possible to detect if the user turn off the cellphone while using my app? Here I'm caring about turning off the cellphone not locking the screen.
Also this event should be distinguished between press the home button and lock the screen.

Comment: Why? It's not like you can do anything when the phone is shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. I just did a quick search of the docs and it is not possible. As bolclock said it is unlikely that you can do anything when the phone is shut down anyway.